# Old versions of packages in ROS repository

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The latest version of the ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins package (2.3.2-0precise-20130920-2002-+0000) is broken ([this bug](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/120)) and I want to downgrade it to the previous version. The ROS repository however seems to have only the latest version of the package. Where can I get older versions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84371/old-versions-of-packages-in-ros-repository/) by [munnveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/6052/munnveed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to find the complete revision history on github, where you linked to.

If you are looking for older versions via apt, I think you're out of luck. There are no different versioned apt repositories.

The only thing you might be able to try, if this is newly introduced, is switch to a ROS mirror in the hope that this one hasn't updated yet.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [munnveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/6052/munnveed/) on 2013-09-28**:
Ok, thank you. I guess I will just compile from source in github.